# How to modify the position of a single View inside a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-recyclerview

I've implemented a `RecyclerView` that based on a Preference value, displays a variable number of buttons. This is the situation:

**What I would like to have**

[image]

**What I currently have**

[image]

I am using a `GridLayoutManager` to display the buttons but I have many doubts about how to get the result I want. I've tryed to work with the span size and other things but with no results. Should I override `onLayoutChildren()` or is there an easier solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 3);
gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        return 3 - position % 3;
    }
});
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it's not the layout that I look for